# For how many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is $\sqrt{n^2+2379}$ natural?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Here's my attempt at a solution: the expression $\sqrt{n^2+2379}$ is natural iff  $$n^2 + 2379 = x^2, \quad \mbox{ for some } x \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Therefore $$(x+n)(x-n)=2379=3 \cdot 13 \cdot 61.$$

I try to represent $2379$ as a product of two natural numbers, this can be done in four ways:

$$2379=(3 \cdot 13 )\cdot 61$$
$$2379=3 \cdot (13 \cdot 61)$$
$$2379=(3 \cdot 61)\cdot 13$$
$$2379=1 \cdot 2379 $$

Comparing these options to $(x-n)(x+n)=2379$ produces four pairs, since $$(x-n)(x+n) = ab \implies x=(a+b)/2, \ n= (a-b)/2, \quad \mbox{ assuming } a>b.$$

The four $n$'s are then $11,85,395,1189$. Is my solution correct? Is there a way of doing this more theoretically, without knowing explicitly the prime factorization of $2379$?

Comment: Yes, all the steps are correct. I won't check your arithmetic at the end, but that's the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct (I used [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2-n%5E2+%3D+2379+in+integers) to double check the arithmetic).  If one has a list of all solutions, it is easy to trace them back to the prime factors of $2379$, so essentially it is necessary to have the factorization in order to know all the solutions.

While the problem only asks for the *number* of solutions, this is equivalent to knowing the number of divisors of $2379$.  I think it is widely believed that counting divisors is just as hard as factoring, but this has not been proven to my knowledge.